# SQL Select all items from all clients with its last price

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with all purchases made. with these columns:

```
clientnumber,    
articlenumber,  
datepurchased,    
price,  
 qty
```

Sample data: (I have got more that 1000 clients and more than 50 products)

```
client1 - article1 - price 100 - qty 2 - date xx-xx-xxxx
client1 - article1 - price 111 - qty 5 - date xx-xx-xxxx
client1 - article2 - price 1   - qty 5 - date xx-xx-xxxx
client2 - article1 - price 114 - qty 5 - date xx-xx-xxxx
client2 - article1 - price 500 - qty 6 - date xx-xx-xxxx
```

etc..

i want get a list back that gives me all articles from each client purchased with its last price for each article and each client like this

```
Client 1, Artikel 1, 50 USD (this price should be the newest datepurchased)
client 1, articel 5, 30 usd
clients 2, articel 1, 30 usd
client 2, articel 2, 20 usd
```

...

Comment: please tag the dbms you are using

Comment: DBMS = database management system (in case English and our acronyms aren't your first language).

Comment: please share some sample data and expected result,you can use group by/rownumber..but sharing some sample data helps

Comment: how do you know the newest datepurchased ? Please provide some sample data in the correct table structures. There is no way your sample data is really like that in one table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to rank your records per client and item and show only the best ranked row (here: the latest purchase). Use `ROW_NUMBER` to do that.

```
select clientnumber, articlenumber, price
from
(
  select 
    clientnumber, articlenumber, price,
    row_number() over (partition by clientnumber, articlenumber 
                       order by datepurchased desc) as rn
  from purchases
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: thanks that seems to work! I have to studdy what exactly are you doing here but it looks good.

Comment: Yes study this; it's worth it :-) If you have problems understanding it, come back and ask.

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT clientnumber, 
   articlenumber, 
   datepurchased, 
   (SELECT (yourtable.price / yourtable.qty) as unitPrice FROM yourtable yt      WHERE yt.articlenumber = yourtable.articlenumber ORDER BY datepurchased DESC  LIMIT 1) as latestPrice , 
   qty 
 FROM   yourtable 
 ORDER BY datepurchased DESC
```

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers to a question. Post one answer, and then edit it if you need change it.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 articlenumber, 
         clientnumber, 
         datepurchased, 
         (yourtable.price / yourtable.qty) as pricePerArticle , 
         qty 
         FROM   yourtable 
         ORDER BY datepurchased DESC
```